# Understanding syntax for defining a relation.

Tags: relations

Let T = {1, 2, 3, 4} and A = T * T. We can define a relation R on A;

> (a,b)R(c,d) <=> (a/b)=(c/d)
>
> For example:
>
> (1,2)R(2,4) since (1/2)=(2/4)

Does this mean that ((1,2),(2,4)) ∈ R

**or**

(1,2) ∈ R *and* (2,4) ∈ R

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to show that R is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that  ((1,2),(2,4)) ∈ R